# Subtract 5 hours from sysdate in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I need to subtract 5 hours from sysdate in Redshift. Is there a quick function for that? I tried to do:

```
select date((sysdate -  cast('5 hour' as interval)))
```

This is returning only the date part. I need to be in this format:

if sysdate is 2019-03-01 16:17:57.543081, my output should be 
2019-03-01 11:17:57.543081

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also do that using following command.

```
select now() - interval '5 hour';
```

Comment: On Redshift - [01000] Function "now()" not supported. Better use the current_time

Comment: use `GETDATE()` in Redshift instead of `NOW()`

Answer (score 3):

You just need to simplify like this

```
select current_timestamp - interval '5 hour';
```